# Can a virus on a host computer infect VM?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

Can a virus on the host computer infect a VM?

I know virus on a VM can theoretically infect the host, but it isn't likely, but I'm wondering about the inverse.

Comment: Of course. The VM is really just files on the host computer. Files can be infected

Comment: Yes, If a host operating system is infected, a VM can be infected, likewise, it's possible for an infected VM to infect the host operating system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply put, yes. A hypervisor is software running on the host, and it presents and controls the virtual hardware upon which the guest executes, so it can do absolutely anything to the guest that its virtual hardware supports, like monitoring/altering instructions passed to the physical CPU, I/O to the physical disk or network, and just about anything else.

An OS can't effectively distrust its hardware (about the furtherest it can go is to distrust the drivers), so control over the virtual hardware presented by the host is as good as (or even better than) physical access to the box, from the attackers perspective.

Now all that said, the terms "virus" and "infect" are not correct in this case. For the most part, viruses are dead. They stopped being a viable means of malware transmission about 2005. Nowadays its all about Trojans and the occasional worm.  Viruses target software that can communicate with remote systems, and uses that communication channel to spread. So a virus might target a specific version of Eudora mail, but if Eudora is patched, the virus can't spread. Worms use OS mechanisms for transmissions, and Trojans trick the user into downloading them.

As such, software on the guest is not "infected" by a "virus", and if it was, you could use standard measures to detect, block, or otherwise defang the guest, because the malware is running on it.

If the Host is compromised, no malcode need appear on the guest at all, in order for its operations to be compromised. so the guest does not need to be "infected" at all to feel the sting of the host compromise. the attack would be likely completely invisible to the guest.